# Flutter in Docker container fails in Jenkins but not locally

Tags: docker, jenkins, flutter

I'm trying to get one of our very simple flutter apps to run its test suite in Jenkins.

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

ARG WORKING_DIR=${HOME}
ARG FLUTTER_ARCHIVE=flutter_linux_v0.5.1-beta.tar.xz

COPY ${FLUTTER_ARCHIVE} ${WORKING_DIR}

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install xz-utils

RUN tar -xf "${WORKING_DIR}/${FLUTTER_ARCHIVE}" 
ENV PATH="${WORKING_DIR}/flutter/bin:${PATH}"

RUN apt-get -y install git libglu1 lib32stdc++6

RUN rm ${WORKING_DIR}/${FLUTTER_ARCHIVE}
```

I build the container on my machine, navigate to the source code directory of the flutter app and run the following command:

`docker run -td -v`pwd`:/source flutter:flutter`

Where `flutter:flutter` is my built image.

I navigate into the container using `docker exec` and execute `flutter packages get` and then `flutter test`. Everything works as expected and all tests pass.

However, when I try to use the exact same Dockerfile through Jenkins, I get following error:

> /flutter/bin/flutter: line 161: /flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart: Permission denied

I'm guessing it has something do with users and that differs somehow between how Jenkins runs and how it works when I run the steps manually. The steps in the Jenkinsfile are exactly as what I ran manually above:

```
stages {
    stage('test') {
        steps {
            script {
                sh 'flutter packages get'
                sh 'flutter test'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have pointed to our local registry where the image resides:

```
agent {
    docker "flutter:flutter"
}
```

I am out of ideas and I don't really know how to solve this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have tried the following:

- Creating a user in the Dockerfile using `useradd` and then switching to that user using `USER <user>` Dockerfile syntax and performing all operations as that user.
- Creating a user in the Dockerfile using `useradd`, performing all operations as root but then setting `chown user:user -R /flutter` to change ownership of Flutter directory

Both of the above required me to add the following to the Jenkinsfile:

```
agent {
    docker {
        image 'flutter:flutter'
        args '-u user --privileged'
    }
}
```

But still no luck.